# Add node week count?

Tags: 7, nodes

Drupal just stores the day count and the total count. Is there a way to give a week count to the node?

**ps**: i want to show a node title list.the sort creteria is decending the most viewsd in a week. by defaule Drupal just stores the day count and the total count. there is no week count.

**could i use this**: i add a node created time in a sql query which `where` clause is less than  `time()-24*7` like this `where node time created < time()-24*7`)then i use the total node count. then descending the result. the node title show will be the same as the week count. am i right? if right, how to put the sql query to views sort creteria .

Comment: If you have the total number of times the node has been viewed in a day, you can calculate the total number the node has been visited in a week. This question is too generic; you should ask a more specific question if there is something more specific you don't understand. Differently, the question is not Drupal-related.

Comment: The "node_counter" table is not used, in Drupal 7; if the code you are writing will be ported to Drupal 7, you should consider this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this *not so well maintained* module [Statistics Granularity](http://drupal.org/project/statistics_granularity) or learn how to do it yourself with this blog post: [Advanced statistics for Drupal: most viewed nodes in a week, month, ...](http://www.jochus.be/site/2010-12-08/drupal/advanced-statistics-drupal-most-viewed-nodes-in-a-week-month)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using views3, you can use the `GROUP BY` functions and do it via SQL.  Alternatively there is a seperate module for views2.